# Can I see some of Amsterdam during a five hour layover at Schiphol?

Tags: amsterdam, stopovers, ams

I'm changing planes in late March in Schiphol with a five hour layover. I've never been to Amsterdam.

Is there anything I can do to see a little bit of Amsterdam and not miss my flight?

Comment: I assume you either have a Schengen visa or do not need one.  In that case, you can take the train to the city.  You might have enough time to spend an hour or two there if your arriving flight is not delayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have the visa problem, the train station is at the basement of the airport. Take the train to Amsterdam Centraal and you will reach the city centre. You can spend a good couple of hours there.

Comment: With 5 hours between flights, during the day you will get 2 hours in the city at most, between 11 PM and 6 AM it may go down to one hour as the trains only run once an hour.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is possible. The train from Schiphol airport to Amsterdam Central station takes about 18 min (www.ns.nl). From central station there are several sites nearby: you can walk through the 'Kalverstraat' to the Royal Palace at the 'Dam' in just 10-15 minutes for example. However, take into account the time to leave the airport and return to the departure gate in time (some gates are a long way).